# Calling a function returning promise results in browser loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to pass a function in a directive $scope so that it can be called from the markup template. The function itself is defined in an injected service as follows:

```
        isEditable: function (item) {
            return getAccount().then(function (account) {
                return account.authorities.indexOf('ROLE_ADMIN') != -1 || item.publicationState == "DRAFT";
            });
        }
```

and passed on to the scope simply as:

```
        $scope.isEditable = service.isEditable;
```

Whenever I run the code, the browser gets stuck in a CPU hogging loop. I'm obviously missing something...

Best,
Edoardo

Comment: Your function `isEditable` neither returning a promise nor takes a callback. How do you expect to use the result of this call?

Comment: duh... c&p mishap, see question edit. Still stuck in a loop

Comment: Problem in getAccount() maybe, dont see anything else.